# Jenkins starts chromedriver in background mode (like headless mode)

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver

I've setup Jenkins server on windows 10 machine. When running the job(simply `mvn test -DsuiteXmlFile=%TestSuite%`) the job successfully compiles and starts tests. I can see first being skipped, second failed and then it starts passing one after one. No Chrome window is opened, but when I check in task manager I can see it opens several Chrome processes in background. When calling `mvn test -DsuiteXmlFile=TestSuite` in CMD(also in power shell) it opens Chrome in front.
Looking at Jenkins logs I see that it creates a .bat file in c:/System/TEMP/ directory and executes that batch file. I've even tried to copy the file, put in my project's root and call it via CMD, the same .bat file works as expected. Still jenkins opens Chrome in background. Any idea what causes this and how can I force Jenkins to run tests in Foreground?

My chromedriver vesion is 78.0.3904.70(if needed).
Logs are identical for both cases:

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running TestSuite
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
18.11.2019 03:50:38.019 INFO  - [AutomationListener]:Staring to run test suite with 11 tests
Nov 18, 2019 3:50:38 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities chrome
INFO: Using `new ChromeOptions()` is preferred to `DesiredCapabilities.chrome()`
Starting ChromeDriver 78.0.3904.70 (edb9c9f3de0247fd912a77b7f6cae7447f6d3ad5-refs/branch-heads/3904@{#800}) on port 39924
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
[1574077841.726][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
Nov 18, 2019 3:50:43 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
[1574077845.835][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
18.11.2019 03:50:55.489 INFO  - [BasePage]:The element: By.cssSelector: polygon is clicked
18.11.2019 03:50:55.494 INFO  - [AutomationListener]:----------------------------------------------------------------------
18.11.2019 03:50:55.495 INFO  - [AutomationListener]:Starting to run TestMethod test method
18.11.2019 03:50:55.495 INFO  - [AutomationListener]:----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Check again after disabling the firewall on the windows system.

Answer (score 2):

When the Jenkins slave run as service in the background every program it initiate, like running the batch file, will also be in the background. The solution is to run the Jenkins slave as a regular program in the foreground.

Comment: saying honestly I am new to Windows :) used to use it in far 2008 :). Yet, I don't have slave, all setup + test is running on the same windows machine, and jenkins is running as a system service.

Comment: @AshotArakelyan I see, I'm not devops but this seems to be unusual setting. Anyway this is the issue, running in the background. You can create Jenkins slave, although it's local, and run it in the foreground, and do the work through the slave.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the slave solution is working in my case.

I have also a window machine, I have configured the Jenkins and also configured the slave within the machine and now it every time opens the browser in the foreground.

I know it's not the genuine solution but it works perfectly